# Ruby factorial loop

Tags: ruby

Am I doing this wrong? I am trying to write a simple program to ask the user to enter a number until they wish to quit, but when I run the program it gives me an argument error stating bad value for range. what can I do to fix this problem?

```
var = true

  while var == true
    print "Enter a number ('Q/q to quit'): "
    input = gets.chomp
  if input == 'Q' || input == 'q'
    var = false
    puts "Goodbye!"
  else
    product = 1
    for i in 1..input
      product = product * i
    end
  end
end
  puts "#{input}! is #{product}"
```

Comment: What `gets` receives from the input is a string, you need to manually convert it to numeric: `for i in 1..input.to_i`.

Comment: Should change the input to input.to_i and also as per this logic I don't see how this would calculate factorial...I guess it would always ask the question even though you enter a number...

Comment: and what if I enter 'a'...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is "input" is a string. You can't use it in your range. You need to convert it to a int.

change this:

```
for i in 1..input.to_i
```

Comment: Really that was it? Wow thank you! I was trying to figure that out for an hour.

Comment: You can use a string range of course i.e. `"1"..input`.

Comment: Or `input = gets.to_i` (the `chomp` is no longer necessary)